# Saving columns' widths in result grid in MySQL Workbench

Tags: mysql, mysql-workbench

Each time I run a query, the columns' widths in the result grid in MySQL Workbench are reset:

[image]

Is there any way to prevent this? According to the [bug tracker](http://bugs.mysql.com/bug.php?id=57328), this issue was fixed 3.5 years ago.

Comment: Since there's already a bug entry there's no sense in asking an SO question about this. The issue will be addressed in a future MySQL Workbench release.

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because it is asking to circumvent an obvious and reported bug.

Comment: As mentioned in the question, according to the bug tracker, this issue was fixed 3.5 years ago. This means that now I don't know whether this is a bug or there is an option somewhere...

Comment: Ah, I see, I had a different bug report in mind. Anyway, this is a reported and know problem and will be fixed.

Comment: It was (and is still) working properly until version 6.0.7.11215.  but seem to be broken in latest version 6.1.4.11773. Quite irritating! :(

Comment: Good to know, well I left a comment on the [bug tracker](http://bugs.mysql.com/bug.php?id=57328).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Thankfuly, this annoying bug was fixed in Workbench version 6.2+. I tested it with freshly downloaded v6.2.3.12312, 64-bit.

A heads up if you're using **Windows** non-installer version (i.e. zip): there is a new dependency which, if missing, causes it to break upon startup: Visual C++ Redistributable. Thankfully, installer version checks for this and lets you download it first.
If you're not using the installer, here's the direct link to Microsoft site: http://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=40784.

Answer (score 1):

There seems to be a bug tracker with this issue open :

http://bugs.mysql.com/bug.php?id=72332

```
Open a SQL editor to a server and execute a query that returns some text fields, the  
columns don't autofit to a reasonable width to display as much as they can (or set in 
the  Preferences as I believe 256 bytes..). Instead they are displayed in a super   
narrow table taking 1/20 of the screen width.
```

It seems to have changed with 6.1

Other way to expand panel

[image]

Let me know in case if you finding difficulty.